# How to use collapse and accordion in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am new to angular 4. I am doing designing using angular 4 along with bootstrap 4. I am trying to use collapse with accordion. My coding below

```html
<div id="accordion">
      <div class="card ">
          <div class="card-header text-white bg-primary" >
            <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
               List <i class="float-right fa fa-caret-down"></i> 
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="Container ">
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                              <label class="Bold">Product Id </label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" >
                         
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                                <label class="Bold">Description </label>               
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" >
                         
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
                                </div>
                      </div>                               
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

but when I click card Header, it didn't collapse and also it directs me to the Login page. How to fix this?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/m4dTsI3EmHuijPKPNfDz?p=preview

Comment: Is there any other way to use this or can you explain this?? U r using array ,as I am new to angular 4 I dont understand your code